# application is not installed on your phone error in android

Tags: android, smartphone, android-debug

I am beginner in android programming.

This problem occured when I run application on android device from eclipse.
I have run same application many times, But when I run it today device restarted automatically and after that all app shortcuts icon changed to default android icon, and in app list icon is writen SD at bottom-right.

When I click icon its giving message "application is not installed on your phone".

I worked around this, In most solution its saying that these are apps installed in SD card, but dont know what happened with this app.
In my device no memory card is attached but when I check My files sdcard is showing in path.

I restared device couple of times but it didnt solved.

Comment: Go to factory data reset and reset your device. But you must loose your data. So take backup before you do

Comment: @V.J.Fectory reset ?, I am thinking to do this but this is shared device between some developer. So it would be better is some solutions found to solve this.

Comment: wait until these are loaded from SD card, because these are stored in SD card. This is not big problem for every device like this only

Comment: have You any time installed it with a signed apk? If Yes, You have to delete this first from Your phone..

Comment: @AlluHow much time it may take? I am working around for last 2 hours..

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I have uninstalled all apps that I have installed during development(installed by apk or direct from eclipse.)

Comment: there is a "problems" tab in logcat, is there any problem reported?

Answer (score 1):

```
GO to Settings > Apps > Google Play > Clear Cache/ Clear Data
```

Comment: Problem is Play store is also corrupted like other apps.

Comment: I checked in all app list, But Play Store is not displaying in list